# Why does Android Studio compile my whole app to launch a primitive unit test?

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, gradle, junit

Whenever I launch a unit test "from the margin menu" (see screenshot), that does not have any Android dependencies, Android Studio compiles my whole app only to run one primitive assert.

Is it the intended behaviour that my app needs to fully compile? I was expecting that unit tests are extremely fast and compile only those classes mentioned in the test and their dependent classes are to be compiled for unit testing.

[image: run a test from margin menu]

Moreover, if I add any Android class, e.g. `Application` or `AppCompatActivity`, to the test it will still complete successfully. Every article about testing on Android says that it's impossible to run a unit test that depends on any Android library.

Comment: Is it actually slow? At least the second time it should be launching extremely quick. And what good is a unit test that doesn't touch any of your other classes? Optimizing the startup time for that use case doesn't seem like a good use of limited resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle projects are usually structured to have a `main` source set and a `test` source set. They are compiled separately and `test` is configured to depend on `main`. All Gradle knows is that it needs `main` if it is supposed to run `test`. Therefore it compiles all of `main` before compiling `test`. You can see that in action when compiling `test` if you look at the "build" panel. In fact, if any class in `main` has syntax errors it will not even try to compile `test` even if that class is not needed for `test`.